# Compare two tables and highlight different values

Tags: sql

Hi I have two tables Test1 and Test2.

One is a copy of the other so they have the same columns (ID, LastDiaryEvent, Impact, Prority, Status, Name) and values. Test1 gets an update and changes a value in one of the columns (say Status as an example).

I know the code to compare the two tables

```
select * from Test1
except
select * from Test2;
```

But this brings back the entire row and I need to specify the value that has been changed changed.

So,

TEST1 + TEST2

```
ID  LastDiaryEvent  Impact  Priority    Status      Name
277199  2013-07-10  Problem Standard    Customer    BAILEYB
```

Then TEST1 table is updated so the row reads

```
ID  LastDiaryEvent  Impact  Priority    Status      Name
277199  2013-07-10  Problem Standard    Action          BAILEYB
```

So the status value has changed. I can compare the two rows but want to know how to specify that it is the Status value that has changed. Note, I'm using Status as an example, only the ID value will no be changed,

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean the values that are in `test2` that are not in `test1`?? and what RDBMS you are using??

Comment: The changed column is always `Status`?

Comment: Hi, I mean that Test1 is updated in some way. Either by changing the value of an existing row or adding a completely new row.

Comment: Add sample data and what you expect as output.

Answer (score 1):

There are several cases to check

- New row in table2
- Deleted row in table2
- Changed value **or values** in table2

Note the last bit: several values may change.

This code returns a series of flags to show *what* has changed

```
CREATE TABLE #test1 (ID int, Impact varchar(100), NAME varchar(100), STATUS char(1));
CREATE TABLE #test2 (ID int, Impact varchar(100), NAME varchar(100), STATUS char(1));
GO
INSERT #test1 VALUES (1, 'xx', 'name1', 'A'), (2, 'zz', 'name2', 'B'), (3, 'xx', 'name3', 'B'), (4, 'xx', 'name4', 'A');
INSERT #test2 VALUES (1, 'xx', 'name1', 'A'), /*(2, 'xx', 'name2', 'B'),*/ (3, 'xx', 'name33', 'B'), (4, 'yy', 'name4', 'A'), (5, 'zz', 'name5', 'B');
GO


SELECT
    0 AS MissingRowinT2,
    0 AS NewRowinT2,
    CASE WHEN T1.STATUS <> T2.STATUS THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS StatusChanged,
    CASE WHEN T1.NAME <> T2.NAME THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS NAMEChanged,
    CASE WHEN T1.Impact <> T2.Impact THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS ImpactChanged,
    *
FROM
    #test1 T1
    JOIN
    #test2 T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (
    select T1.*
    INTERSECT
    select T2.*
    )
UNION ALL
SELECT
    SIGN(ISNULL(T2.ID, 1)), SIGN(ISNULL(T1.ID, 1)), 0, 0, 0, *
FROM
    #test1 T1
    FULL OUTER JOIN
    #test2 T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
WHERE
    T1.ID IS NULL OR T2.ID IS NULL
GO
```

IF you need it spelled out

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(
        CASE WHEN T1.STATUS <> T2.STATUS THEN ',Status' ELSE '' END +
        CASE WHEN T1.NAME <> T2.NAME THEN ',NAME,' ELSE '' END +
        CASE WHEN T1.Impact <> T2.Impact THEN ',Impact' ELSE '' END,
        2, 8000) AS WhatCHanged,
    *
FROM
    #test1 T1
    JOIN
    #test2 T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (
    select T1.*
    INTERSECT
    select T2.*
    )
UNION ALL
SELECT
    CASE WHEN T1.ID IS NULL THEN 'NewRow' ELSE 'Deleted Row' END, *
FROM
    #test1 T1
    FULL OUTER JOIN
    #test2 T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
WHERE
    T1.ID IS NULL OR T2.ID IS NULL
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
SELECT 'Status Change' as Change, t1.*
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID 
WHERE t1.Status != t2.Status
UNION ALL
SELECT 'LastDiaryEvent Change' as Change, t1.*
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID 
WHERE t1.LastDiaryEvent != t2.LastDiaryEvent
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Priority Change' as Change, t1.*
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID 
WHERE t1.Priority != t2.Priority
```

as will this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN t1.Status != t2.Status THEN 'Status Change' 
            WHEN t1.LastDiaryEvent != t2.LastDiaryEvent) THEN 'LastDiaryEvent Change'
            WHEN t1.Priority != t2.Priority THEN 'Priority Change' 
            ELSE 'Panic!'END AS Chanage, t1.*
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID 
WHERE t1.Status != t2.Status OR
 t1.LastDiaryEvent != t2.LastDiaryEvent OR
 t1.Priority != t2.Priority
```

NB - I join only on ID = ID... you may want / need to join on more stuff as your data model dictates.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the ID never changes, I think a `JOIN` and `CASE` is appropriate:

```
SELECT
(SELECT CASE WHEN t1.LastDiaryEvent <> t2.LastDiaryEvent 
THEN 'diary event changed' ELSE '' END),
(SELECT CASE WHEN t1.Impact <> t2.Impact 
THEN 'impact changed' ELSE '' END),
(SELECT CASE WHEN t1.Priority <> t2.Priority 
THEN 'priority changed' ELSE '' END)
(SELECT CASE WHEN t1.Status <> t2.Status
THEN 'status changed' ELSE '' END)
(SELECT CASE WHEN t1.Name <> t2.Name
THEN 'name changed' ELSE '' END)
 FROM Test1 t1
INNER JOIN Test2 t2 ON (Test1.ID = Test2.ID)
```

your example would return:

```
'', '', '', 'status changed', ''
```